# How to generate CVBR AV file with .MP4 or .TS files

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

All,

I have to generated a .MP4 or .TS with CVBR[constrained]bitrate mode, Kindly help me command for the same.

I came to know that i can generated using libpous.
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html

But i fail to get a command for AV files with CVBR, Kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate a constrained bitrate H.264 stream, use

```
ffmpeg -i input -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1000k output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native CVBR mode, but you can "simulate" it by tuning the parameters of ABR:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 1000k output
```

In the above example, `-bufsize` is the "rate control buffer" so it will enforce your requested "average" (4000k in this case) across each 1000k worth of video. So basically it is assumed that the receiver/end player will buffer that much data so it's ok to fluctuate within that much.

Comment: He asked for Constrained VBR which is peak-constrained, not near CBR. Your command achieves the later. There's only an upper limit for CVBR, no `minrate`.